# trouble with configuring client using node-xmpp-client

Tags: node.js, http, xmpp, messaging, node-xmpp

I'm trying to create an XMPP HTTP gateway in nodejs using node-xmpp-client and adastra.re as an xmpp server. I've never worked with xmpp before and I'm having trouble configuring the client.

var client = new XMPP.Client({
    jid: ???,
    password: '***',
    host: "https://adastra.re/"
    bosh: ????
  })

What exactly are jid and bosh? I initially thought that jid was an email of the client you want to log in as and your password would be your password for the email. But that appears to not be the case. And I've been having trouble understanding what bosh is too. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

XMPP server does not understand HTTP protocol. Bosh will work as a mediator between your your HTTP request and XMPP server.
JID is the user id registered in you XMPP server. For example 
my XMPP server is AdAstre.re , it could be Mahesh@Adastre.re.

I hope that helps.

Comment: for learning purpose you can try with [ink]bosh.metajack.im:5280/xmpp-httpbind bosh service